# "Послушай что внутри" — нужна ли тут запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

> Послушай, что внутри.

Запятая точно нужна?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Послушай, что внутри.**

Запятая ставится. Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным изъяснительным.

Первое предложение односоставное (определенно-личное), *послушай* ― сказуемое.

Второе предложение двусоставное эллиптического вида: *что* ― подлежащее, *внутри* ― обстоятельство.

Answer (score 2):

Точно нужна. Это сложное предложение.